# Bootstrap Grid Side by side Dropdowns in Table

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

[image]I need to have 3 dropdowns placed side to side in td using bootstrap grid.

**html**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class='col-xs-12'>
</div>
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Day</th>
      <th>Open 24h</th>
      <th>Open at</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="col-xs-1">Monday</td>
      <td class="col-xs-1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="" value="">24Hours
      </td>
      <td class="col-xs-1">
        <select class="form-control">
                <option value="12"></option>
              </select>
      </td>
      <td class="col-xs-1">
        <select class="form-control">
                <option value="00"></option>
              </select>
      </td>
      <td class="col-xs-1">
        <select class="form-control">
                <option value="AM"></option>
              </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

The 3 dropdowns must be below open in header.
Could anyone please help , aligning dropdowns so that they are side by side.

Comment: what do u mean.. do u had a roughly sketch of it

Comment: I have posted a sketch, I need the same.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean like this?
Just need to add a **row** and **col**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class='col-xs-12'>
</div>
<table class="table table-hover" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Day</th>
      <th>Open 24h</th>
      <th>Open at</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="col-xs-1">Monday</td>
      <td class="col-xs-1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="" value="">24Hours
      </td>
      <td>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-4">
        <select class="form-control">
                <option value="12"></option>
              </select>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
        <select class="form-control">
                <option value="00"></option>
              </select>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
        <select class="form-control">
                <option value="AM"></option>
              </select>
</div>
</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: @Aditya did u mean it got squeeze and become to small?

Comment: I want all the headers and data fitted as in rough sketch ,

Comment: Only one large  dropdown appear instead of 3

Comment: Can u show me the result? based on snippet.. it was ok with showing 3 dropdown

Answer (score -1):

**Updated**

How about this?
https://jsfiddle.net/mps4Lb14/1/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class='col-xs-12'>
</div>
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Day</th>
        <th>Open 24h</th>
        <th>Open at</th>
        <th>Closes at</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-1">Monday</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" value="">24Hours
        </td>
        <td class="col-xs-5">
            <div class = 'form-inline'>
            <select class="col-sm-2">
                <option value="12"></option>
            </select>
            <select class="col-sm-2">
                <option value="00"></option>
            </select>
            <select class="col-sm-2">
                <option value="AM"></option>
            </select>
            </div>
        </td>

        <td class="col-xs-5 " style='text-align:left;'>
            <div class = 'form-inline'>
            <select class="col-sm-2">
                <option value="12"></option>
            </select>
            <select class="col-sm-2">
                <option value="00"></option>
            </select>
            <select class="col-sm-2">
                <option value="AM"></option>
            </select>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I dont need to apply css property (width) , I need it using complete bootstrap grid only.

Comment: I need similar,but want space after each dropdown

Comment: Also need to display default values 12 00 AM. in dropdown

Comment: @Aditya, google it out. Its even more straightforward from here onwards.

Comment: sorry,  I found it useful.

Comment: but I didn't get how to give spacing betwween each dropdown?